# Xamarin: recyclerview OutOfMemory exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I'm using a recyclerview, that crashes and gives an OOM exception after scrolling a bit down.

> 01-09 02:32:56.169 W/System.err( 6816): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 43 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 3GB until OOM

How do I improve my code? Do I need to dispose stuff or does it happen automatically? Because I find mixed answers about that after googling.

adapter

```
    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder
               OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                    Inflate(Resource.Layout.MomentListItem, parent, false);
        MomentViewHolder vh = new MomentViewHolder(itemView);
        vh.llMain.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            //Check if you don't get a negative position from the header.
            if (vh.AdapterPosition >= 0)
            {
                //Fix the position to leave out the header as a moment
                int ajustedPosition = vh.AdapterPosition;

                // Create a new fragment and a transaction.
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTx = mActivity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                MomentFragment aDifferentDetailsFrag = new MomentFragment();

                // Create a bundle to pack the argumants.
                Bundle utilBundle = new Bundle();
                utilBundle.PutString("ID", mItems[ajustedPosition].momentID);
                utilBundle.PutString("Title", mItems[ajustedPosition].title);
                utilBundle.PutString("Content", mItems[ajustedPosition].content);
                utilBundle.PutString("Author", mItems[ajustedPosition].author);
                utilBundle.PutString("Day", mItems[ajustedPosition].day);
                utilBundle.PutString("Month", mItems[ajustedPosition].month);
                utilBundle.PutString("Time", mItems[ajustedPosition].time);
                utilBundle.PutString("ImageURL", mItems[ajustedPosition].imageurl);

                // Replace the fragment that is in the View fragment_container (if applicable).
                fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.frameLayout1, aDifferentDetailsFrag);

                // Add the transaction to the back stack.
                fragmentTx.AddToBackStack(null);

                // Commit the transaction.
                fragmentTx.Commit();

                //Put Argument
                aDifferentDetailsFrag.Arguments = utilBundle;
            }
        };
        return vh;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        MomentViewHolder vh = holder as MomentViewHolder;
        var item = mItems[holder.AdapterPosition];

        string baseURL = "http://203.195.147.70:8080/daringduckBackend/api/pictures/";
        vh.textTitle.Text = item.title;
        //            vh.textContent.Text = 
        vh.textAuthor.Text = item.author;
        vh.textMonth.Text = item.month;
        vh.textDay.Text = item.day;
        vh.textTime.Text = item.time;
        vh.textContent.Text = "";

        if (item.imageurl != "")
        {
            string avatarURL = string.Concat(baseURL, item.imageurl);
            Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable(vh.ivAvatar, avatarURL);
        }

        if (item.momentImgurl != "")
        {
            string momentIMGurl = string.Concat(baseURL, item.momentImgurl);
            Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable(vh.ivImage, momentIMGurl);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW (and not answering your original question), I think you should probably have `else` clauses to ensure that the image is cleared if the URL _is_ `""`. We had similar code, and it seems that the "recycler" part of RecyclerView means the individual cells get re-used. We ended up with a "random" image in the cases where it should have been blank - wasn't entirely random, just the last image that that particular instance had been displaying.

Comment: Thank you! That is actually one of the issues i'm struggling with right now! How do i properly clear an image? Something like this:                 vh.ivAvatar.SetImageDrawable(null);?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar problem, issue was in the picture rendering. Try to make your images smaller. Also try to use [Picasso](https://components.xamarin.com/view/square.picasso) component to render images.

P.S.: I mean smaller not inside view, but on the server side.